# USB flash disks unusable after trying to make bootable kill disk

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive, formatting, diskpart

I have an issue with 2 USB flash disks which worked great before I tried to create bootable flash drives with Kill disk on it, using the Kill Disk tool. I did not wipe the drive with it, just to add.

Since then both USBs are not working. When plugged into 2 different PCs, the sound is heard, but the disk is not visible in the Explorer. I managed to delete the volume once but that was all I was able to accomplish. Now in disk management, the file says it's online and there is a primary partition, when I check the Disk management and I try to format, it tells me the drive is offline. When I try to assign a letter it says that the system can't find the file. I have google and went the cmd and diskpart way. Diskpart is showing there is a primary partition on the device and when listed the volumes, it has status as "unusable" and status offline. I tried to run clean but got the error: The device is not ready. I can't create another primary partition since there is one already.

The second disk is exactly the same.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Accept an answer ([more info here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/355310)) to indicate the problem is solved. There is no need to litter the title.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Kill Disk tool justifies its name.

It's possible that the two disks were nearing their end of life,
and the hard thrashing they got from Kill Disk, writing again and again
all their sectors, just pushed them into oblivion.

It's perhaps time to buy new flash disks.

Comment: I mean. I did not wiped those disks with Kill Disk. Those disks were like a year old and  rarely used. The Kill Disk application has the feature to make a bootable disk with Kill Disk app on it. So I can wipe different PC without booting them. Not that I would be "cleaning" those flash drives with it. I already used the tool few times and without problem.

Comment: Do you mean that the disks were just lying around, and now when you try them they are completely unusable?

Comment: No. I used the disks yesterday and was able to copy to/from the both USBs and they were working fine. Then I had to wipe/delete 2 laptops at work. Used licensed Active Kill Disk that has Boot Disk Creator, to make a flask disk which I can boot up and erase all the data on the laptop. It said it successfully created Bootable disks and then when I tried to use them, it was not able to boot. So I plugged it back into PC which did not recognize it and since then I am trying to make those USBs work. I used this tool several times before and never happened.

Comment: Is it possible that the drive on which you created the disks was defective and destroyed the disks?

Comment: I am not sure, is there anything else I can try?

Comment: If the disk is showing in Disk Management as offline, try to right-click it and set it to Online.

Comment: It's showing as online and healthy. But when trying to do any action in Disk Management, it either shows error, that the disk is offline or the system cannot find the file specified. Basically the same as in here. However diskpart was not able to clean it. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disk-management-change-driver-letter-shows-it/002dd0db-e624-4c71-98ad-567f8f102dfc

Comment: (1) Try to fix the disk signature ([useful link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/fixing-disk-signature-collisions/ba-p/724114)). (2) Years ago I found that if the first physical byte of the disk is corrupted, the disk becomes unusable, like yours. I was able to use some software (don't remember which) to copy this byte from a working disk, and the disk was fixed. But I cannot at this date give directions on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

So, I fixed it. Downloaded AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard.

At first, I tried to rebuild MBR, then Format, add a path letter and it seemed to be working. But when I plugged it into a different PC, it was not working and seemed like before. So I did wipe the device through AOMEI and then I was able to format it in Disk Manager. The USB flash drive is now working in both PCs

Answer (score 0):

This is doable without AOMEI.

In windows you can sometimes go to diskpart, select the volume, and clean.

https://www.seagate.com/support/kb/how-to-diskpart-eraseclean-a-drive-through-the-command-prompt-005929en/

Disclaimer however depending on what the issue is this does not *always* work, so there is a method two that almost always does, in fact if the disk is not damaged, this has never failed to work for me over many years.

Pop the disk in a linux system (or live boot one of your preference)

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/{device name} bs=1M count=10
```

Where `{device name}` is the name of the disk not the partition on it, so if you have a `/dev/sdb` and a `/dev/sdb1` sdb1 will be a partition, you want the root device.

What this does is completely overwrite the partition table, 10M is way overkill, but fast and certain.

This is sometimes encountered with disks that were part of raid sets as well, not only flash disks.

That will correct ANY format issue on a disk essentially making it forget anything related to format.